# SQL: Duplicate rows with unique values and change a column value

Tags: mysql

I'm a new SQL-user and I need some help.

I have a table with multiple columns filled with data. The two columns of interest are called "course_id" and "year".

What I am trying to do is copy all rows with unique "course_id"'s to new rows with the same data but with different years. I find it hard to explain exactly what I want, so here is an example (ordered by course_id):

```
id        year          course_id
1         2014          1
2         2015          1
3         2014          2
4         2015          2
5         2016          2
6         2014          3
```

and if I want to update this table to add the year "2017" I would get:

```
id        year          course_id
1         2014          1
2         2015          1
7         2017          1
3         2014          2
4         2015          2
5         2016          2
8         2017          2
6         2014          3
9         2017          3
```

All rows with the same course ID has the same data, so ID 7 would have the same data as ID 1 and 2, but with the column "year" different.

Being so new to SQL I have a hard time realizing a solution to this. Can anyone with experience help me?

Comment: Can we assume that your column id is an auto_increment id, so we don't need to think of ways how to insert correct IDs?

Comment: Yes the column id is an auto_increment id.

Comment: Please revise tags, MySQL (*Oracle*) and SQL-Server (*Mircosoft*) are two different things.

Comment: Whoops! Shows how much I know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server (Square brackets around `year`):

You can `insert` the `distinct` `course_id`s from the table, along with a value for `year` like so:

```
insert into tbl ([year],course_id)
select distinct 
    2017
  , course_id
from tbl
```

In MySQL:

```
insert into tbl (`year`,course_id)
select distinct 
    2017
  , course_id
from tbl
```

Comment: This was not exactly what I needed, as I had more data than two columns, but this solution + some more research lead to a solution that worked :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd also advice to use `NOT EXISTS` if so that query can be reran multiple times and it will never throw a PK violation exception. Maybe it's not needed in your case.

```
INSERT INTO tbl (`year`, course_id)
SELECT DISTINCT 2017, course_id
FROM tbl AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (   SELECT 1
                     FROM tbl AS t2
                     WHERE t2.course_id = t1.course_id
                     AND t2.`year` = 2017);
```

Also, for best performance you could add a index, so that engine can seek for records efficiently.

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl ` ADD INDEX `ix_tbl_year_course_id` (`year`, `course_id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an efficient solution but it will work. Write a query in any programming language

```
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
    Statement s1 = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery(select distinct course_id from tbl);
    while(rs.next()){
    String item = rs.getString("course_id");
    String query="insert into tbl(year,course_id) values('2017',"+item+")";
    ResultSet rs1 = s1.executeQuery(query);
    }
```

I am hoping you are aware with "how to interact with a database using a programming language.